# php if mobile_device_detect is true conditional statement

Tags: php, conditional-statements, return

I don't understand PHP very well... not good start I know.

I'm using http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/ for mobile/desktop website, and I'm using wordpress as my CMS.

I have set up my function like so...

```
    require_once('mobile_device_detect.php');
    mobile_device_detect(true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false);
```

But now in my theme, I want a conditional statement similar to this...

```
    <?php if (is_home()) { ?>

        //Some bits here
    <?php } else { ?>
        //Some bits here
    <?php } ?>
```

Though I want it to return the values from my function. See below my rubbish attempt below...

```
    <?php if (mobile_device_detect==true) { ?>

        //Some bits here
    <?php } else { ?>
        //Some bits here
    <?php } ?>
```

Obviously this is not going to work lol, but can you see what I'm trying to achieve? and help would be most awesome thanks!

Cheers
Josh

Comment: I've got no answer, but I'm amazed by the ridiculous number of "Buy Now" buttons on that `detectmobilebrowsers` website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there.

```
require_once('php/mobile_device_detect.php');
$mobile = mobile_device_detect(true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false);
```

Then check for

```
if ($mobile==true) // then do the rest of your stuff
```